# What are the best practices to unify access to data classes properties

Tags: oop, kotlin, generics, inheritance

I have a class ExpenseDto

```
data class ExpenseDto(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val aggregationA: ExpenseAggregationA,
    val aggregationB: ExpenseAggregationB,
    val aggregationC: ExpenseAggregationC,
)
```

And all its associations have the same fields. And what are the best practies that can be applied here to universalize it

```
data class ExpenseAggregationA(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String? = null
)

data class ExpenseAggregationB(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String? = null
)

data class ExpenseAggregationC(
    val id: Int,
    val text: String? = null
)
```

Comment: Can't you just use 1 data class `ExpenseAggregation`? Or do you want the types to be separate?

Comment: I need the types to be separate because they have relationship to different schemas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data class`es can inherit from a `sealed class`.

```
sealed class ExpenseAggParent (val id: Int, val text: String? = null) {
    data class ExpAggA( override val id: Int, override ...)
    data class ...
    data class ...
}
```

Besides that, sometimes I like to have "property unifier" interfaces, especially when refactoring a legacy code with classes with the same semantics but different names of the properties:

```
interface HasId(val id: Int)

data class ExpenseAggregationX(
   override val id: Int,
   ...
): HasId

data class ExpenseAggregationY: HasId {

   val someOtherNameButStillId: Int

   override val id: Int
       get() = this.someOtherNameButStillId
}
```

And, of course, you can use the good old interface, but for that, you may re-use the above approach:

```
interface ExpenseAggregation: HasId, HasText

data class ExpenseAggregationA(
    override val id: Int,
    ...
): ExpenseAggregation

// Other approach for classes with other existing names, see above
data class ExpenseAggregationB: ExpenseAggregation {
    ...
}
```

This is close to a mix-in approach which Kotlin does not currently support directly, but for completeness, [there are delegations](https://dzone.com/articles/mixins-with-kotlin) usable if your class is rather a service than a DTO.